# I can't add Style using the HTMLElement

Tags: jquery, class, styles, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to collect the elements by class and store them in a variable using `document.getElementsByClassName('class')`. When I do a console log of these elements it returns the elements correctly.

[image]

[image]

but when I try to add a style.display = 'none' I get an error with the 'style' . When I hover over the style the error tells me the following: ' Property 'style' does not exist on type 'HTMLCollectionOf'.

[image]

[image]

I tried adding as HTMLCollectionOf at the end, but I still get the same error.

```
let rows_hide = document.getElementsByClassName('brand-'+ element) as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
```

I have also tried putting `rows_hide[0].style.display = 'none'` but it still doesn't fix it. I have tried several combinations with these solutions that I have found in the answers of other questions like using .addClass and adding the styles in the CSS file. But it still doesn't work.

[image]

How could I add `display : ' none'` to the elements I collect ?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. We don't debug images here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that getElementByClassName returns every with this class name.

If you only want the first, you may use

```
document.querySelector(".class")
```

or if you want to change style for each element something like this should do the trick

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName("class")].forEach(el => (el as HTMLElement).style.display="none")
```

Comment: I just tried it, I still get the same error. 
any
Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'. '

Comment: Ok I hadn't realize you were using typescript, I just updated the second snippet, let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

This trick work for me you can try it:

```
 let element = document.querySelector(".test_class")
    if(element)
        element.style.display = "none";
```

or

```
$(".test_class").css({ "display": 'none' })
```